# Get class based on variable generic class

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the solution to achieve the following:

```
public final static <T> Class<Set<T>> getSetClass(Class<T> cls) {
    ...
}
```

Where `cls` is for example `String.class` and the method then returns the `Class<Set<String>>` object. But of course, as `cls` is variable, it could also get `Boolean.class` and then return a `Class<Set<Boolean>>` object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) , may be solving your problem.

Comment: @Thilo I want to use a JSONPath library in a generic application where the return type is not known beforehand. So I need to execute this method: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonContext.java#L157 where I can pass the expected return class. Sometimes I explicitly expect a Set of JSONObjects or a Set of Strings. I hoped I could achieve that this way..

Comment: I don't know that library, but that's probably what this `TypeRef` is for. A `Class` object won't capture enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public <T> Class<Set<T>> getSetClass(Class<T> cls) { 
  Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(); 
  return (Class<Set<T>>) set.getClass();
}
```

Well, it compiles; how useful it is to solve your "real" problem; I can't tell yet. And obviously; that *cls* parameters goes unused here.

But it does something:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Class<Set<Integer>> setClass = new PartitionPropertiesTest().getSetClass(Integer.class);
    System.out.println("whatever: " + setClass);
}
```

prints:

```
whatever: class java.util.HashSet
```

Comment: But note that this generates a type warning (suppressed here), because the returned Class instance does not contain any information about `T`. All it knows is that it is a `Set` of something (the nature of which has been erased).

Comment: I don't know how useful this is either, but this library I use wants to get the expected return type as a Class object. And I really want a Set of Strings or a Set of JSONObjects. So thanks, I'm going to accept this answer as it answers my question. Thanks also to @Thilo for pointing me to some of the theory.

Comment: I think the library wants you to use the `TypeRef` version of the method instead of the `Class` version (for this exact reason): https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/TypeRef.java

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Class<Set<String>>` object.

Generic types are erased at runtime, so there is only an instance of `Class<Set>` (namely `Set<?>.class`) shared by all the `Class<Set<?>>`. There is no way to get back to `String` from this object.

For this very reason, [your JSON library has a `TypeRef` class](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/TypeRef.java) to capture the generic type information. You just use that instead of `Class`.

Comment: How can I achieve this with the `TypeRef` then? In the documentation of `TypeRef` I also just see `TypeRef ref = new TypeRef<List<Integer>>() { };` which is not going to solve my problem, as that `Integer` part should be parameterized...

Comment: The documentation claims to capture the `Integer` part.

Comment: This only works because you are making an anonymous subclass of `TypeRef` here (not the `{}` at the end). That way, the compiler has this information.

Answer (score -1):

You mean, how to define that the return type depends on the parameter type?

Try this:

```
public final static <T> Class<Set<T>> getSetClass(Class<T> cls) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah that's the better way to define the method, but I'm looking for the actual body of the method to achieve it..

Comment: Your Question was not clear on what the problem is, an your code snippet only showed the method signature, so I thought there's the problem.